# I'm new to mysql, I would like to call the function to this table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
create table mysql_sequences( 
    sequence_name varchar(256), 
    value   int(38)
); 

insert into mysql_sequences values ('device_sequence', 1); 
insert into mysql_sequences values ('device_sequence2', 2); 
insert into mysql_sequences values ('device_sequence3', 3); 
insert into mysql_sequences values ('device_sequence4', 4); 
insert into mysql_sequences values ('device_sequence5', 5); 
insert into mysql_sequences values ('device_sequence6', 6); 

commit; 
select * from mysql_sequences;

DELIMITER // 
create function next_val (p_sequence_name varchar)
returns number
 
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA

begin 
declare val int; 
select value into val 
from mysql_sequences 
where sequence_name = p_sequence_name for update; 

update mysql_sequences set value = value +1 
where sequence_name = p_sequence_name; 

return val + 1; 
end; 
DELIMITER //
```

Comment: You cannot CALL a function. 'to invoke a stored function, refer to it in an expression.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html Please give an example with sample data and expected outcome of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your function definition

```
varchar must have a length

number data type is invalid - should be int 

If you have to use delimiters end should be followed by the delimiter not ;

the delimiter reset should be delimiter ;
```

Otherwise the function works without error...

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1894da3d520a9763488a09198f979ee6

Comment: MUCH APPRECIATED!. I have fixed the errors, but I would like to use the function on a table to see the result of the function. do u know how I can do that because youtube doesn't have videos for functions on  mysql workbench.

Comment: You cannot CALL a function. 'to invoke a stored function, refer to it in an expression.' dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html Please give an example with sample data and expected outcome of what you are trying to do

Comment: okay, I understood you. I didn't clarify my answer, I wanted the function to do auto increment and lock the row so whenever something else call the same row it well do new row then it will give the result.

Comment: It is doing that. You need to call it in your insert statement.